# Android Design Screen for different screen size

Tags: android

[app screen on galaxy s4 it skip right and bottom part because of small size mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YlH0.png)
I am having problem in Design different screen size.

how should all 5 categories  will support most of the mobile screen?

my Android App Design Normal screen works on 5 inch mobile screen where as for 4 inch screen it skip below content.
for example it work nice on samsang galaxy s4 (5 inch) also on nexus 4.

but  as shown in image when i see on nexus S(4 inch screen) it skip some bottom and right part .it cannot hold full layout mostly top and left part it display.

how to design normal screen which support these screen size changes? 
is it compulsory to use wrap_content or Match_parent or fill_parent only to get rid of it.

for that also i am confused of specifying image size for different screen size in drawable.

also is normal screen be of different density such as hdpi,mdpi,ldpi etc.
how to solve this issue is it sufficient to use dp and sp?

and last one, in Android Studio we design 5 types of layout.for example activity_channel_list.xml(small). etc( for normal,large,xLarge).what last just activity_channel_list.xml represent.is it like if not any layout is selected.this will be selected by default.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check here for details of different screen sizes. - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html     and also have look at this  - http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to design layouts for different screens then make folders accordingly link

layout-mdpi

layout-hdpi

layout-xhdpi

layout-xxhdpi

If you don't want create different layout for different screens then simply use dimension file and create different dimens in that like 
values-hdpi (dimen)
values-xhdpi (dimen)
values-xxhdpi (dimen)

and the difference between dp and sp is, we use dp for give dimensions to the image, and for size purpose and sp is use for define text size

Comment: i have designed for screen as you said in answer.but my problem is normal screen size not displayed fully in 4inch.at 5 inch screen it display well and corrent.how to manage that difference?.i am designing screen for normal screen layout.i

Comment: What you mean by normal screen? each screen having dpi resolution. Please Mention your problem clearly.

Comment: i have designed normal screen in terms of mobile size between 3 to 5 inch.now, for dpi level i have designed on nexus 4.and also tested on real samsung galaxy s4.it looks fine on nexus 4. but not nexus S as i shown in figure in question.

Answer (score 0):

the screen size id efferent and you cant make a layout for every one you need to try categorize the screen with layout selector

if you use sp for text the text size will change when user change the android font size and it is better to use dp for text

and last Question is like first one you need to categorize layout for size and density normaly

Comment: actually i am using android studio. in that layout folder i am having five layout (large,small,normal ,xlarge and last one is unnamed).i want to ask which design layout it represent other than four.

Comment: If you design only one layout then it works for all dpi, only problem is it didn't look same and consistence in each device for that purpose we are design dpi wise layouts.

Answer (score 0):

How should all 5 categories will support most of the mobile screen?

Take care if these following aspects while designing layouts:

1.Always design layouts inside scrollview, so that for smaller screens user will be able to view complete layout by scrolling

2.Use sp for text Sizes

3.Use dip(density independent pixels) for all widget sizes, usage of dip makes the size of widget according to mobile profile(like 240*320 may use ldpi so according widget size will change)

4.All the icons you are using you need to generate for all profiles(ldpi,hdpi,xxhdpi,xhdpi) and store in drawable-xxxx folder

If you dont want to generate images for all profiles you can use font icons (like [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/android/),[iconmoon](https://icomoon.io/#icons-icomoon))

font icons appear according to screen sizes.

5.Last but not least, avoid using hardcoded margins between widgets use attributes like gravity,center_in_parent etc.. so that screen looks uniform in all devices.